# Gnome installation

Tags: gnome

I downloaded the Gnome Shell but I cannot get it to run. I am a newbee to Ubuntu and seriously dislike Unity. I want to run Gnome, as this looks like a desktop/GUI I would be comfortable with. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. I am currently running 11.10.

Comment: What method did you use to download and install it?  What do you mean but can't get it to run;  Can you see it as a option on the login screen but not get it to start or is it not there at all?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to:

1. Log off.
2. Click the Ubuntu icon beside your name.
3. Click GNOME.
4. Log in as normal. Welcome to GNOME!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Provided they installed Gnome-Shell properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Bring up a terminal (press control alt and t to do this) and type

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback

Log out and click the little symbol where you type your password. Choose gnome classic and log back in. When you do this the trash can will be gone so get a terminal up and type

gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible true

Comment: He asked for Gnome Shell, not Gnome Classic.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and execute the following

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

You should have an active internet connection